# XSL 1.0 Multilevel grouping with empty tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

This is my first time posting here, so I apologize in advance for the length and for any format issue or lack of information. I've been working on this problem for a few days and I've researched my problem extensively but haven't found a solution yet, so I am hoping someone here can help me. It's an xslt related issue and I only started coding in xslt a couple of months ago so I'm not so experienced.

Basically, I have an input XML which may contain duplicate records as well as empty tags and I need to reorganize them into a javascript associative array to be able to manipulate and display the values efficiently on the client side.

**My question is: Is there a way to do a multilevel grouping even if the used field tag is empty. If not, is there a way I can edit the xml in xsl by replacing the empty tag with a keyword and then applying the rest of my templates?**

To understand my problem here are the details.
This is my input XML

```
<cds>
    <sections>
        <section name="myteam_CurrentAgeCompleteSection" link="false">
            <detail name="">
                <record>
                    <field name="AGERANGEID">30-39</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFCOUNTAGE">1</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00000100</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Human Resources</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="AGERANGEID">&gt;=70</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFCOUNTAGE">5</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00000100</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Human Resources</field>
                </record>
            </detail>
        </section>
        <section name="myteam_CurrentGenderCompleteSection" link="false">
            <detail name="">
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00000100</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Human Resources</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">5</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">2</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00000100</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Human Resources</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">7</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">1</field>
                </record>
            </detail>
        </section>
        <section name="myteam_CurrentRaceCompleteSection" link="false">
            <detail name="">
                <record>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Human Resources</field>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00000100</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFRACE">10.0</field>
                    <field name="RACENAME" />
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Human Resources</field>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00000100</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFRACE">1</field>
                    <field name="RACENAME">Asian</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Human Resources</field>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00000100</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFRACE">1</field>
                    <field name="RACENAME">American Indian</field>
                </record>
            </detail>
        </section>
        <section name="myteam_ChildAgeColumnSection" link="false">
            <detail name="">
                <record>
                    <field name="AGERANGEID">40-49</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFCOUNTAGE">1</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000013</field>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">IT computer center (D)</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="AGERANGEID">50-59</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFCOUNTAGE">2</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000013</field>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">IT computer center (D)</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="AGERANGEID">&gt;=70</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFCOUNTAGE">5</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000013</field>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">IT computer center (D)</field>
                </record>
            </detail>
        </section>

        <section name="myteam_ChildGenderColumnSection" link="false">
            <detail name="">
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000013</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">IT computer center (D)</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">4</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">2</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000147</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Personnel Administration (D)</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">3</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">1</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000013</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">IT computer center (D)</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">4</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">1</field>
                </record>
            </detail>
        </section>
        <section name="myteam_ChildGenderColumnSection" link="false">
            <detail name="">
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000013</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">IT computer center (D)</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">4</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">2</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000147</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Personnel Administration (D)</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">3</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">1</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000013</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">IT computer center (D)</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">4</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">1</field>
                </record>
            </detail>
        </section>
        <section name="myteam_ChildGenderColumnSection" link="false">
            <detail name="">
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000013</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">IT computer center (D)</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">4</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">2</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000147</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Personnel Administration (D)</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">3</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">1</field>
                </record>
            </detail>
        </section>
    </sections>
</cds>
```

I looked online and found that the best way to deal with multilevel grouping is to use xsl:key and generate-id(). That worked great and the data came out exactly as I wanted to, so the flow of my xsl is correct. But unfortunately if the field used in the xsl:key is an empty tag, when I go into the multilevel grouping using concat(), it fails.

```
<!-- Start external variables -->   
<!-- Field names -->
<xsl:variable name="ageFieldName" select="'AGERANGEID'" />
<xsl:variable name="genderFieldName" select="'GENDER'" />
<xsl:variable name="raceFieldName" select="'RACENAME'" />
<xsl:variable name="ouIdFieldName" select="'ORGUNITID'" />
<xsl:variable name="ouNameFieldName" select="'ORGUNITNAME'" />

<!-- Keys -->   
<xsl:key use="field[@name='AGERANGEID']" name="AGERANGEID" match="detail/record" />
<xsl:key use="concat(field[@name='AGERANGEID'],'|', field[@name='ORGUNITID'])" name="AGERANGEID_merge" match="detail/record" />
<xsl:key use="field[@name='GENDER']" name="GENDER" match="detail/record" />
<xsl:key use="concat(field[@name='GENDER'],'|', field[@name='ORGUNITID'])" name="GENDER_merge" match="detail/record" />
<xsl:key use="field[@name='RACENAME']" name="RACENAME" match="detail/record" />
<xsl:key use="concat(field[@name='RACENAME'],'|', field[@name='ORGUNITID'])" name="RACENAME_merge" match="detail/record" />

<xsl:key use="field[@name='ORGUNITID']" name="ORGUNITID" match="detail/record" />


<xsl:template match="/">
    var analyticsMap = {<xsl:call-template name="buildAnalyticsTable" />};
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="buildAnalyticsTable">       
    <!-- Age -->
    "<xsl:value-of select="$ageFieldName"/>" : {
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="buildAnalyticsTableRangeLevel" select="//detail/record[generate-id()=generate-id(key($ageFieldName, field[@name=$ageFieldName]))]">
        <xsl:with-param name="keyName" select="$ageFieldName"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="countField" select="'NUMOFCOUNTAGE'"/>     
        <xsl:with-param name="label" select="'Age Range'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="isGender" select="'false'" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    },

    <!-- Gender -->
    "<xsl:value-of select="$genderFieldName"/>" : {
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="buildAnalyticsTableRangeLevel" select="//detail/record[generate-id()=generate-id(key($genderFieldName, field[@name=$genderFieldName]))]">
        <xsl:with-param name="keyName" select="$genderFieldName"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="countField" select="'NUMOFGENDERCOUNT'"/>  
        <xsl:with-param name="label" select="'Gender'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="isGender" select="'true'" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    },

    <!-- Race -->
    "<xsl:value-of select="$raceFieldName"/>" : {
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="buildAnalyticsTableRangeLevel" select="//detail/record[generate-id()=generate-id(key($raceFieldName, field[@name=$raceFieldName]))]">
        <xsl:with-param name="keyName" select="$raceFieldName"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="countField" select="'NUMOFRACE'"/>     
        <xsl:with-param name="label" select="'Race'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="isGender" select="'true'" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    }

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="detail/record" mode="buildAnalyticsTableRangeLevel">
    <xsl:param name="keyName" />
    <xsl:param name="countField" /> 
    <xsl:param name="label" />
    <xsl:param name="isGender" />
    <xsl:variable name="value" >
        <xsl:call-template name="testForUnknown">
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="field[@name=$keyName]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="name">
        <xsl:call-template name="testForGender">
            <xsl:with-param name="isGender" select="$isGender"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="$value"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    "<xsl:value-of select="$value"/>" : {       
    "analyticsLabel" : "<xsl:value-of select="$label"/>",
    "analyticsName" : "<xsl:value-of select="$name"/>",
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="buildAnalyticsTableCountLevel" select="key($keyName, field[@name=$keyName])[generate-id()=generate-id(key(concat($keyName, '_merge'), concat(field[@name=$keyName],'|', field[@name=$ouIdFieldName])))]">
        <xsl:with-param name="countField" select="$countField"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    },          
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="detail/record" mode="buildAnalyticsTableCountLevel">
    <xsl:param name="countField" />
    "<xsl:value-of select="field[@name=$ouIdFieldName]"/>" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "<xsl:value-of select="field[@name=$ouNameFieldName]"/>",
    "analyticsValue" : "<xsl:value-of select="field[@name=$countField]"/>"
    },
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template name="testForUnknown">
    <xsl:param name="name" /> 
    <xsl:choose>        
        <xsl:when test="string-length($name) = 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="'Unknown'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$name" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="testForGender">
    <xsl:param name="isGender" />
    <xsl:param name="name" /> 
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$isGender = 'true' and $name = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="'male'" />            
        </xsl:when> 
        <xsl:when test="$isGender = 'true' and $name = 2">
            <xsl:value-of select="'female'" />      
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$name" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the output of my transformation

```
    var analyticsMap = {        

    "AGERANGEID" : {


    "30-39" : {     
    "analyticsLabel" : "Age Range",
    "analyticsName" : "30-39",

    "00001001" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "Human Resources",
    "analyticsValue" : "1"
    },

    },          


    "&gt;=70" : {       
    "analyticsLabel" : "Age Range",
    "analyticsName" : "&gt;=70",

    "00001001" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "Human Resources",
    "analyticsValue" : "5"
    },

    "50000013" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "IT computer center (D)",
    "analyticsValue" : "5"
    },

    },          


    "40-49" : {     
    "analyticsLabel" : "Age Range",
    "analyticsName" : "40-49",

    "50000013" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "IT computer center (D)",
    "analyticsValue" : "1"
    },

    },          


    "50-59" : {     
    "analyticsLabel" : "Age Range",
    "analyticsName" : "50-59",

    "50000013" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "IT computer center (D)",
    "analyticsValue" : "2"
    },

    },          

    },


    "GENDER" : {


    "2" : {     
    "analyticsLabel" : "Gender",
    "analyticsName" : "female",

    "00001001" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "Human Resources",
    "analyticsValue" : "5"
    },

    "50000013" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "IT computer center (D)",
    "analyticsValue" : "4"
    },

    },          


    "1" : {     
    "analyticsLabel" : "Gender",
    "analyticsName" : "male",

    "00001001" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "Human Resources",
    "analyticsValue" : "7"
    },

    "50000147" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "Personnel Administration (D)",
    "analyticsValue" : "3"
    },

    "50000013" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "IT computer center (D)",
    "analyticsValue" : "4"
    },

    },          

    },


    "RACENAME" : {


    "Unknown" : {       
    "analyticsLabel" : "Race",
    "analyticsName" : "Unknown",

    },          


    "Asian" : {     
    "analyticsLabel" : "Race",
    "analyticsName" : "Asian",

    "00001001" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "Human Resources",
    "analyticsValue" : "1"
    },

    },          


    "American Indian" : {       
    "analyticsLabel" : "Race",
    "analyticsName" : "American Indian",

    "00001001" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "Human Resources",
    "analyticsValue" : "1"
    },

    },          

    }

};
```

As you can see, in the Race->Unknown section, it doesn't complete it by applying the template mode "buildAnalyticsTableCountLevel" so I never get the ORGUNITID information which is very important in what I am doing.

I unfortunately cannot edit the xml coming in as this is a part of a much bigger framework used in various projects and I cannot change it. So I have to work with what I get.

I tried using the string() method in xsl:key but that makes everything worse. Any tips or help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change the start of the stylesheet like this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <my:unknown>Unknown</my:unknown>
```

and change one of the `key` definitions to:

```
 <xsl:key name="RACENAME_merge" match="detail/record" 
  use="concat((field[@name='RACENAME']
              |document('')/*/my:unknown[not(field[@name='RACENAME'])]),
              '|', field[@name='ORGUNITID'])"  />
```

Finally, change one of the `xsl:apply-templaes` to this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="buildAnalyticsTableCountLevel"
select="key($keyName, field[@name=$keyName])
          [generate-id()=generate-id(key(concat($keyName, '_merge'),
          concat((field[@name=$keyName]
                 |document('')/*/my:unknown[not(current()/field[@name='RACENAME'])]),
                 '|', field[@name=$ouIdFieldName])))]">
    <xsl:with-param name="countField" select="$countField"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

**The complete code after these changes becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <my:unknown>Unknown</my:unknown>

 <!-- Start external variables -->
 <!-- Field names -->
 <xsl:variable name="ageFieldName" select="'AGERANGEID'" />
 <xsl:variable name="genderFieldName" select="'GENDER'" />
 <xsl:variable name="raceFieldName" select="'RACENAME'" />
 <xsl:variable name="ouIdFieldName" select="'ORGUNITID'" />
 <xsl:variable name="ouNameFieldName" select="'ORGUNITNAME'" />

 <!-- Keys -->
 <xsl:key use="field[@name='AGERANGEID']" name="AGERANGEID" match="detail/record" />
 <xsl:key use="concat(field[@name='AGERANGEID'],'|', field[@name='ORGUNITID'])" name="AGERANGEID_merge" match="detail/record" />
 <xsl:key use="field[@name='GENDER']" name="GENDER" match="detail/record" />
 <xsl:key use="concat(field[@name='GENDER'],'|', field[@name='ORGUNITID'])" name="GENDER_merge" match="detail/record" />
 <xsl:key use="field[@name='RACENAME']" name="RACENAME" match="detail/record" />
 <xsl:key use="concat((field[@name='RACENAME']
                     |document('')/*/my:unknown[not(current()/field[@name='RACENAME'])]),
                     '|', field[@name='ORGUNITID'])"
  name="RACENAME_merge" match="detail/record" />

 <xsl:key use="field[@name='ORGUNITID']" name="ORGUNITID" match="detail/record" />


 <xsl:template match="/">
    var analyticsMap = {<xsl:call-template name="buildAnalyticsTable" />};
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="buildAnalyticsTable">
    <!-- Age -->
    "<xsl:value-of select="$ageFieldName"/>" : {
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="buildAnalyticsTableRangeLevel" select="//detail/record[generate-id()=generate-id(key($ageFieldName, field[@name=$ageFieldName]))]">
        <xsl:with-param name="keyName" select="$ageFieldName"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="countField" select="'NUMOFCOUNTAGE'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="label" select="'Age Range'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="isGender" select="'false'" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    },

    <!-- Gender -->
    "<xsl:value-of select="$genderFieldName"/>" : {
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="buildAnalyticsTableRangeLevel" select="//detail/record[generate-id()=generate-id(key($genderFieldName, field[@name=$genderFieldName]))]">
        <xsl:with-param name="keyName" select="$genderFieldName"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="countField" select="'NUMOFGENDERCOUNT'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="label" select="'Gender'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="isGender" select="'true'" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    },

    <!-- Race -->
    "<xsl:value-of select="$raceFieldName"/>" : {
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="buildAnalyticsTableRangeLevel" select="//detail/record[generate-id()=generate-id(key($raceFieldName, field[@name=$raceFieldName]))]">
        <xsl:with-param name="keyName" select="$raceFieldName"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="countField" select="'NUMOFRACE'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="label" select="'Race'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="isGender" select="'true'" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    }

 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="detail/record" mode="buildAnalyticsTableRangeLevel">
    <xsl:param name="keyName" />
    <xsl:param name="countField" />
    <xsl:param name="label" />
    <xsl:param name="isGender" />
    <xsl:variable name="value" >
        <xsl:call-template name="testForUnknown">
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="field[@name=$keyName]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="name">
        <xsl:call-template name="testForGender">
            <xsl:with-param name="isGender" select="$isGender"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="$value"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    "<xsl:value-of select="$value"/>" : {
    "analyticsLabel" : "<xsl:value-of select="$label"/>",
    "analyticsName" : "<xsl:value-of select="$name"/>",
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="buildAnalyticsTableCountLevel"
    select="key($keyName, field[@name=$keyName])
              [generate-id()=generate-id(key(concat($keyName, '_merge'),
              concat((field[@name=$keyName]
                     |document('')/*/my:unknown[not(current()/field[@name='RACENAME'])]),
                     '|', field[@name=$ouIdFieldName])))]">
        <xsl:with-param name="countField" select="$countField"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    },
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="detail/record" mode="buildAnalyticsTableCountLevel">
    <xsl:param name="countField" />
    "<xsl:value-of select="field[@name=$ouIdFieldName]"/>" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "<xsl:value-of select="field[@name=$ouNameFieldName]"/>",
    "analyticsValue" : "<xsl:value-of select="field[@name=$countField]"/>"
    },
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="testForUnknown">
    <xsl:param name="name" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($name) = 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="'Unknown'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$name" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="testForGender">
    <xsl:param name="isGender" />
    <xsl:param name="name" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$isGender = 'true' and $name = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="'male'" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$isGender = 'true' and $name = 2">
            <xsl:value-of select="'female'" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$name" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<cds>
    <sections>
        <section name="myteam_CurrentAgeCompleteSection" link="false">
            <detail name="">
                <record>
                    <field name="AGERANGEID">30-39</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFCOUNTAGE">1</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00000100</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Human Resources</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="AGERANGEID">&gt;=70</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFCOUNTAGE">5</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00000100</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Human Resources</field>
                </record>
            </detail>
        </section>
        <section name="myteam_CurrentGenderCompleteSection" link="false">
            <detail name="">
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00000100</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Human Resources</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">5</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">2</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00000100</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Human Resources</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">7</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">1</field>
                </record>
            </detail>
        </section>
        <section name="myteam_CurrentRaceCompleteSection" link="false">
            <detail name="">
                <record>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Human Resources</field>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00000100</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFRACE">10.0</field>
                    <field name="RACENAME" />
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Human Resources</field>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00000100</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFRACE">1</field>
                    <field name="RACENAME">Asian</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Human Resources</field>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00000100</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFRACE">1</field>
                    <field name="RACENAME">American Indian</field>
                </record>
            </detail>
        </section>
        <section name="myteam_ChildAgeColumnSection" link="false">
            <detail name="">
                <record>
                    <field name="AGERANGEID">40-49</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFCOUNTAGE">1</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000013</field>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">IT computer center (D)</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="AGERANGEID">50-59</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFCOUNTAGE">2</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000013</field>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">IT computer center (D)</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="AGERANGEID">&gt;=70</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFCOUNTAGE">5</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000013</field>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">IT computer center (D)</field>
                </record>
            </detail>
        </section>
        <section name="myteam_ChildGenderColumnSection" link="false">
            <detail name="">
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000013</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">IT computer center (D)</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">4</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">2</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000147</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Personnel Administration (D)</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">3</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">1</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000013</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">IT computer center (D)</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">4</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">1</field>
                </record>
            </detail>
        </section>
        <section name="myteam_ChildGenderColumnSection" link="false">
            <detail name="">
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000013</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">IT computer center (D)</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">4</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">2</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000147</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Personnel Administration (D)</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">3</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">1</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000013</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">IT computer center (D)</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">4</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">1</field>
                </record>
            </detail>
        </section>
        <section name="myteam_ChildGenderColumnSection" link="false">
            <detail name="">
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000013</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">IT computer center (D)</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">4</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">2</field>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <field name="PARENTORGUNITID">00001001</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITID">50000147</field>
                    <field name="ORGUNITNAME">Personnel Administration (D)</field>
                    <field name="NUMOFGENDERCOUNT">3</field>
                    <field name="GENDER">1</field>
                </record>
            </detail>
        </section>
    </sections>
</cds>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
    var analyticsMap = {

    "AGERANGEID" : {


    "30-39" : {
    "analyticsLabel" : "Age Range",
    "analyticsName" : "30-39",

    "00001001" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "Human Resources",
    "analyticsValue" : "1"
    },

    },


    ">=70" : {
    "analyticsLabel" : "Age Range",
    "analyticsName" : ">=70",

    "00001001" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "Human Resources",
    "analyticsValue" : "5"
    },

    "50000013" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "IT computer center (D)",
    "analyticsValue" : "5"
    },

    },


    "40-49" : {
    "analyticsLabel" : "Age Range",
    "analyticsName" : "40-49",

    "50000013" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "IT computer center (D)",
    "analyticsValue" : "1"
    },

    },


    "50-59" : {
    "analyticsLabel" : "Age Range",
    "analyticsName" : "50-59",

    "50000013" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "IT computer center (D)",
    "analyticsValue" : "2"
    },

    },

    },


    "GENDER" : {


    "2" : {
    "analyticsLabel" : "Gender",
    "analyticsName" : "female",

    "00001001" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "Human Resources",
    "analyticsValue" : "5"
    },

    "50000013" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "IT computer center (D)",
    "analyticsValue" : "4"
    },

    },


    "1" : {
    "analyticsLabel" : "Gender",
    "analyticsName" : "male",

    "00001001" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "Human Resources",
    "analyticsValue" : "7"
    },

    "50000147" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "Personnel Administration (D)",
    "analyticsValue" : "3"
    },

    "50000013" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "IT computer center (D)",
    "analyticsValue" : "4"
    },

    },

    },


    "RACENAME" : {


    "Unknown" : {
    "analyticsLabel" : "Race",
    "analyticsName" : "Unknown",

    "00001001" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "Human Resources",
    "analyticsValue" : "10.0"
    },

    },


    "Asian" : {
    "analyticsLabel" : "Race",
    "analyticsName" : "Asian",

    "00001001" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "Human Resources",
    "analyticsValue" : "1"
    },

    },


    "American Indian" : {
    "analyticsLabel" : "Race",
    "analyticsName" : "American Indian",

    "00001001" : {
    "analyticsOUname" : "Human Resources",
    "analyticsValue" : "1"
    },

    },

    }

 };
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre for your help! Unfortunately I get an error with <my:unknown> which says "The prefix "my" for element "my:unknown" is not bound." so I then get no output from my xsl. If you could also explain to me what the concat command you wrote means so I can learn and understand the process for next time that would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Scratch that, I just noticed I missed the xmlns added in the xsl:stylesheet. But understanding the concept still applies, as well as what was added in xsl:stylesheet, is that like creating an object type? Thanks again for your answer!!

Comment: @yschoueri, Yes, something like that. This is a well-known mechanism to add your own "types" to an XSLT transformation -- any namespaced (not in the xslt namespace) global element can be defined and used.

Comment: cool, good to know :). And what about the concat command, what does it do? Also for some reason, even if I don't change the "<xsl:apply-templates mode="buildAnalyticsTableCountLevel"" select clause to the new concat, it still works, do you know why?

Comment: @yschoueri, I think that in case you don't update the `xsl:apply-templates` you'll get different and most likely incorrect results. As for what `concat()` does -- its role here is exactly the same as in your original code -- to create a string representation of a composite key that is to be used in performing the indexing.

Comment: thanks for your response. So your solution works great when I run my xslt on an xslt debugger but when I try to run it in my application running on a Tomcat Server, the apply-templates causes this error to be thrown "SystemId Unknown; Line #140; Column #299; org.apache.xml.utils.WrappedRuntimeException", do you know the cause and how I can solve this?

Comment: @yschoueri, No, this must be a bug in the XSLT processor you are using. I get the same correct result with .NET XslCompiledTransform, Saxon and Altova.